# mysql query optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

```
SELECT
    b.categoryid,
    SUM(viewcount) AS cnt,
    categoryname
FROM
    bookvisit AS bv
    INNER JOIN book AS b ON b.isbn = bv.isbn
    LEFT JOIN category AS c ON b.categoryid = c.categoryid
WHERE
    b.categoryid IS NOT NULL AND
    b.categoryid <> 0 
GROUP BY
    b.categoryid 
ORDER BY
    cnt DESC,
    bv.isbn
LIMIT 0, 4
```

I have three tables -
book  (contains books information)
bookvisit (book visit info)
category (category master )

What I need is popular categories, above query is fine with two eq_ref but it has a 
Using temporary; Using filesort also

any help ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by your second paragraph?  I don't understand what that means.

Comment: the above query shows me popular categories.   Book is Primary table and contains isbn, categorid and other fields.  bookvisit contains isbn and viewcount fields.  Category table  is master table for     cateories.  So I need to pickup popular categories.   The query does it     I think, we can optimize it.  If I use explain with query it uses two eq_ref (that is a good thing) but explains also tells that it is using "Using temporary; Using filesort"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **@dj_segfault** said, you cannot have an index on an aggregate column in `MySQL` and you will have to write a service that would cache the SUMs in a shapshot table (which you can index).

Here's how you can do it and still have the accurate statistics:

1. Create a snapshot table:

   ```
   category  cnt
   ```

   with a `PRIMARY KEY` on `category`.
2. Create a single-field, single-record table called `snapshot_time`:

   ```
   taken
   ```
3. On a timely basis, fill this table with the query:

   ```
   UPDATE  snapshot_time
   SET     taken = NOW()

   INSERT  
   INTO    snapshot
   SELECT  b.category, COUNT(*) AS new_cnt,
           (
           SELECT  taken
           FROM    snapshot_time
           ) AS new_taken
   FROM    bookvisit bv
   JOIN    book b
   ON      b.isbn = bv.isbn
   WHERE   bv.visit_time <=
           (
           SELECT  taken
           FROM    snapshot_time
           )
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   SET     cnt = new_cnt,
           snapshot_taken = new_taken
   ```
4. Create the following indexes:

   ```
   snapshot (cnt)
   bookvisit (visit_time)
   book (category)
   ```
5. Run this query:

   ```
   SELECT  category,
           cnt +
           (
           SELECT  COUNT(*)
           FROM    bookvisit bv
           JOIN    book b
           ON      b.isbn = bv.isbn
           WHERE   bv.visit_time > 
                   (
                   SELECT  taken
                   FROM    shapshot_time
                   )
                   AND b.category = s.category
           ) AS total
   FROM    snapshot
   WHERE   cnt >=
           (
           SELECT  cnt
           FROM    snapshot
           ORDER BY
                   cnt DESC
           LIMIT 4
           )
           -
           (
           SELECT  COUNT(*)
           FROM    bookvisit
           WHERE   bv.visit_time > 
                   (
                   SELECT  taken
                   FROM    shapshot_time
                   )
           )
   ORDER BY
           total DESC
   LIMIT 4
   ```

The query will return you accurate visit count.

The main idea is that you need to scan only the records in `bookvisit` that were collected after the statistics were cached.

More than that: you don't even have to scan all records in the cached statistics. Since the number of visits only grows, you can only scan the results that can possibly get into the first four.

If the `4th` record has `1,000,000` page views in the snapshot, and `1,000` page views happened after you took the snapshot, you can only select the records from the snapshot with `cnt >= 999,000`. The other records could not theoretically hit this limit, since it would take more than `1K` page views.

The only problem is that you can delete the books or change their categories. In this case you would just need to recalculate the statistics or fall back to your original method.

Comment: hi Quassnoi, Thanks for the reply.  I read your site explainextended.com regularly and I have also sent the same query thing from there also.  I will try for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment from yesterday, I think the problem is you are doing an ORDER BY on a calculated (aggregate) column, so it can't use an index.

The only way around that would be to add a category.viewcount column that you update when you update book.viewcount.  It wouldn't take up much extra space.  The downsides of this solution are:

1. When a book's category changes (which I assume is rare), you'll need to subtract book.viewcount from the old category and add it to the new category
2. Lock contention on the category tables might be a performance problem

If this were me and performance was essential, I would write a separate service that would read in the current stats into memory on startup, and have the system send updates to it and query it to get the latest stats.  That saves locking and writing the category table.

Of course if the numbers don't have to be 100% up to date you can always run the query overnight and cache the results for the day.